# TYPO3 move site from fileadmin into an own extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-7.6.x

I have a TYPO3 version 7.6.2 installation. I have a test.html and a test.css file inside the fileadmin under fileadmin/site/template/test.html and test.css.

Now as a template I have this under the category setup:

```
page >

page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
file = fileadmin/site/template/test.html
}

config.no_cache = 1
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

This works all fine as intended.

But I heard that it is possible and desirable to separate your own files from the fileadmin, which is thought for user files. I heard one can factor them out into an own extension. Now my question would be how? I did the basic tutorial on how to build your own first extension, but it is still not clear to me how to re factor the code i have in test.html and test.css into an own extension. Any kind of resource or advice would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder in `typo3conf/ext` with the name your extension should have. Create an `ext_emconf.php` (copy from another extension and change the values) so that TYPO3 can install it.

Move your template file from fileadmin to `Resources/Private/Templates/Page/Test.html` in your extension. This could be any other place in your extension but there are structuring conventions wich I suggest to follow.

Now change the TypoScript to

```
file = EXT:your_extension_name/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/Test.html
```

Move the CSS and JS files (and everything else wich needs to be publicly available for web requests) to `Resources/Public/CSS`, resp. `Resources/Public/JavaScript` in your extension. Include the files with the same syntax (`EXT:my_extension_name/Resources/Public/...`) in your TypoScript.

You should also consider to move your TypoScript to `Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt` in your extension. And then include it with

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT source:'FILE:EXT:my_extension_name/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt'>
```

in the backend.

Dont forget to install your extension :)

You can read more about good practices in TYPO3 extensions [here](https://usetypo3.com/good-practices-in-extensions.html).

Comment: For faster startup just use Extension Builder to create skeleton of ext :)

Comment: I don't like the Extension Builder since it clutters the folder with tons of unnecessary files which will last there forever, since a beginner does not know which of them can be deleted. An awesome presentation was held by Bejamin Kott (see http://de.slideshare.net/benjaminkott/typo3-the-anatomy-of-sitepackages). The slides will enlighten you and will help you to create state of the art site packges.

Answer (score 0):

**@Daniel** showed how to move template to extension and that's perfectly valid, especially if you plan to create some custom plugins and/or own models/records.

On the other hand you don't need to move it into extension to avoid its manipulation by non-developers. If you do not plan custom plugins it doesn't make deeper sense.

The fastest workaround is moving files apart from the `fileadmin` and it can be for an instance `typo3conf/templates/` in such case your TS will look like:

```
page.10 {
    file = typo3conf/templates/test.html
}
```

*or any other folder structure that you need*

Just remember to block the access to `Private` or `TypoScript` folders by adding `.htaccess` file with content:

```
# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</IfModule>

# Apache >= 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
```

Optionally you can also create additional `File Storage` record on the *page-zero* pointing to this new folder and allow to access it only for full-admins from the **Files** module, in such case you will be able i.e. to replace some background image from BE, but editors will have only access to the `fileadmin`. Skip this option if you are planning to keep template files under some version control system, like GIT, otherwise you'll get merge conflicts soon.

Comment: There is no reason to not create an own extension for the templating. If you stick to the default folder structure of an "extbased" extension and put your TypoScript under /Configuration/TypoScript and your templates under /Resources/Private, the folders will be automatically protected by the default .htaccess file located in the TYPO3 root directory. Furthermore, I do recommend putting .htaccess files in the before mentioned folders to manually protect them. This is a good idea if something happens to the main .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Might you want to move your typoscript/configuration file to your own extension folder for site templating. Yes, you can create your own extension with [extension_builder](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder/) but give a try to flux.

Here is liste what you need for your template:(liste is little bit big ;) aber sure give you good/easy and manageable template)

- [Flux](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/flux)
- [fluidpages](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fluidpages) pages layout
- [fluidcontent](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fluidcontent) custom flexible content
- [vhs](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/vhs) collection of ViewHelpers
- [fluidbootstraptheme](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fluidbootstraptheme) place for your all pages, content [FCE], css, typoscript. your own extension as you want

@ folder structure of fluidbootstraptheme:

- Configuration/TypoScript [place for your typoscript, don't forget to include in setup.txt and if constants then include in constants.txt]
- Resources/Public [place for css,js,images,fonts]
- Resources/Private/Templates/Page [place for your page template as you mention in your question test.html]
- Resources/Private/Templates/Content [place for your custom content element/FCE]
- Resources/Private/Partials [here you can create your own Header.html and Footer.html file for your pages]

@ uses:

- setup.txt http://screencast.com/t/6FjFXxTKCEI
- Page/FrontPage.html http://screencast.com/t/YDceUemd5
- Content/Slider.html http://screencast.com/t/35xeiN5r

@ useful links:

- [fluid](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master.html)
- [flux](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master.html)
- [vhs](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master.html)

@ don't forget to insert statik template

Thanks to NamelessCoder [Claus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162619/claus-due) :)